# output .appendChild on <li> and <span> elements within a map function

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am storing the todo-items on an array of objects. I want to map the array to get the HTML elements. I am able to do this using `innerHTML` but I want to do it with `createElement`.

I am expecting `<li><span>TEXT</span></li>` output but I am getting only `span`. It seems append is not working.

HTML code :

```
<div class="todo">
      <h1>Todo</h1>
      <form name="todo--form">
        <input type="text" name="todo--input" />
        <button
          type="submit"
          name="todo--submit"
          class="p-2 bg-slate-500 rounded"
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
      <ul class="todo--list"></ul>
    </div>
```

JS Code :

```
const addTodoForm = document.querySelector(`[name="todo--form"]`);
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo--list');
const todos = [];

// function getLabel() {}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = this.querySelector(`[name="todo--input"]`).value;
  const item = {
    text: text,
    finished: false,
  };

  if (text) {
    todos.push(item);
    addTodoForm.reset();
    const todoItems = todos.map((todo, i) => {
      let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
      let newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newSpan.textContent = todo.text;
      let newEl = newLi.append(newSpan);
      return newEl;
    });
    console.log(todoItems);
    todoList.append(...todoItems);
  }
  return;
}

addTodoForm.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

I am getting only `<span><span>` as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `<form>` is submitted there's only one item being appended to list at a time so there's no need to build a one item array. BTW event handlers (functions that are bound to an event) don't return values like a normal function can, but there are indirect ways to get values from them (like from your OP code, that array outside of the function pushing objects).

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const form = document.forms.todo;
// Reference <ul>
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
// Define array for storage
let tasks = [];

// Bind "submit" event to <form>
form.onsubmit = handleSubmit;

// Event handlers passes Event Object by default
function handleSubmit(e) {
  // Stop default behavior during a "submit"
  e.preventDefault();
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;

  /*
  Define {item}
  Add current timestamp to object {item}
  Add <input> text to {item}
  Add {item} to [tasks]
  Clear <input>
  */
  let item = {};
  item.log = Date.now();
  item.task = IO.data.value;
  tasks.push(item);
  IO.data.value = '';

  /*
  Create <time>
  Assign timestamp <time>
  Convert timestamp into a readable date and time
  Add formatted datetime as text to <time>
  */
  const log = document.createElement('time');
  log.datetime = item.log;
  let date = new Date(item.log);
  log.textContent = date.toLocaleString();

  /*
  Create <output>
  Add text of <input> to <output>
  */
  const txt = document.createElement('output');
  txt.value = item.task;

  /*
  Create <button>
  Add type, class, and the text: "Delete" to <button>
  */
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.type = 'button';
  btn.className = 'delete';
  btn.textContent = 'Delete';

  // Create <li>
  const li = document.createElement('li');

  // Append like crazy
  li.append(log);
  li.append(txt);
  li.append(btn);
  list.append(li);
  console.log(tasks);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8px 8px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 30% !important;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id='todo'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>ToDo List</legend>
    <input id='data' type="text" required>
    <button class="p-2 bg-slate-500 rounded">Add</button>
    <ul class="list"></ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation also showing better practices. This will help me on my journey.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const todoItems = todos.map((todo, i) => {
     let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
     let newLi = document.createElement('li');
     newSpan.textContent = todo.text;
     let newEl = newLi.append(newSpan);
     return newLi;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it works. However, can you explain why return the ```newLi``` rather than ```newEl```.

Comment: because you need to return an element for dom and newEl is not an element it just returns undefined you don't need to use a variable for that.

Comment: please vote up if helpfull

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code, I believe the newEl variable being created isn't correct. Try changing newLi.append(newSpan) to newLi.appendChild(newSpan)

This is also listed below

```
  if (text) {
    todos.push(item);
    addTodoForm.reset();
    const todoItems = todos.map((todo, i) => {
      let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
      let newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newSpan.textContent = todo.text;
      let newEl = newLi.appendChild(newSpan);
      return newEl;
    });
    console.log(todoItems);
    todoList.append(...todoItems);
  }
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.
Upon reading on the documentation of append and appendChild, it seems elements cannot be saved into a variable upon using these methods.

I just need to return the append `li` element.

```
   const todoItems = todos.map((todo, i) => {
      let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
      let newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('data-index', i);
      const todoTextNode = document.createTextNode(todo.text);
      newSpan.appendChild(todoTextNode);
      newLi.appendChild(newSpan);
      return newLi;
    });
```